# Data Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am dealing with a data set which has the following fields:

```
ID  Person_Name Person_Country
110 Marc    CA
110 Sean    CN
111 Matt    IN
111 Rob     AU
112 Mike    US
```

I intend grouping the data in the following way:

```
ID  Person_Name Person_Country
110 Marc; Sean  CA; CN
111 Matt; Rob   IN; AU
112 Mike        US
```

I tried using the built-in functions like .pivot_table() and .unstack(), but they weren't helpful since I am dealing with non-numeric data.

Comment: Small note: it is usually a bad idea to give your columns names with spaces. It makes them hard to read: is Name the third column? Oh no, it is part of the second column's name. Rather, use dots or underscores as separators.

Comment: Either `df.groupby('ID').agg('; '.join)` or if you want to explicitly state the column names: `df.groupby('ID')[['Person Name', 'Person Country']].agg('; '.join)`.

Comment: This example cannot take advantage of `apply` and it needs the `agg` to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: @BramVanroy - Thanks, implemented your advice!

Comment: @user2285236 - I was trying this approach by referring to similar questions, but it returns the column names instead of the names concatenated together.

Comment: Are you trying with `agg`? It works fine when I try it: https://imgur.com/a/1hExpHF

Comment: @user2285236 - Yes, I am using the .agg.